# If $F, K$ are fields, $F$ algebraically closed, and $F \subseteq K$ then $K = F$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to show that an algebraically closed field $F$ cannot be contained in a larger field $K$. So if $F \subseteq K$ then $F = K$ for all fields $K$.
Here's my attempt at a proof:

For contradiction, Say $F \subsetneq K$. Hence there is an element $k \in K$, $k \not \in F$.

- if $k$ is algebraic over $F$, then we adjoin $k$ into $F$. So consider $F(k) \equiv F[X] / (p)$ for some polynomial $p \in F[X]$. Since $F(k)$ should be a field, we need $(p)$ to be maximal [ring quotient maximal ideal is field]. Since we have that $F$ is algebraically closed, irreducible polynomials [which generate maximal ideals] are going to be linear. Hence $(p)$ is maximal and F$(k)$ is a field iff $p = (x - f_\star)$ for some $f_\star \in F$. But $F[X]/ (x- f_\star) \simeq F$, since quotienting by $(x - f_\star)$ keeps only degree 0 polynomials, which are the constant elements. So we have that $F(k) = F$. Hence we cannot have $k \not \in F$, giving us the desired contradiction.
- If $k$ is transcendental over $F$, I feel that some argument ought to hold, but I don't know how to proceed.

Is there a counter-example, where $F$ is algebraically closed, while still possessing an extension $K = F(k)$ for some $k$ that is transcendental over $F$? The only algebraically closed field I have experience with, $\mathbb C$, does not allow such a thing to happen as far as I am aware.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{C}(x)$?

Comment: It does allow. You can consider the field $\Bbb C(x)$ of complex rational functions.

Comment: @Berci can you describe the field in more detail? I am not sure why this is a _field_: Don't functions of the form $f(x) = p(x)/q(x)$ have poles? How do we define the multiplication?

Comment: given any integral domain, you can define its [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) the same way you would go from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$. In this way, $\Bbb C(x)$ is just the field of fractions of $\Bbb C[x]$. Since $x$ is a formal variable, it doesn't matter that rational functions have poles as functions of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Berci can you write an answer that describes this construction "from scratch"? I really like the explicit nature of this field extension!

Comment: We don't consider the function $x\mapsto p(x)/q(x)$ but as a *formal quotient* $p/q$.

Comment: See the comment of Shibai.

Comment: Note also, that algebraically we *can't distinguish* two distinct (algebraically independent) transcendentals, meaning that in particular the field of fractions $\Bbb Q(x)$ of the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[x]$ is isomorphic to the transcendental extension $\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algebraic numbers are an algebraically closed field that is properly contained in $\mathbb{C}$ and many other fields. For example, if $F$ is the field of algebraic numbers, $K=\mathbb{C}$, and $k=\pi$, then we are precisely in the second case of your proof sketch, and we of course cannot show that $k$ is in $F$.

Given any (algebraically closed field) $F$ one can always construct $F(t)$ where $t$ is transcendental with respect to $F$ to get a bigger field. Then you can take the algebraic closure of $F(t)$ to get a bigger algebraically closed field.

By adjoining *a lot* of transcendentals you can get algebraically closed fields of arbitrarily large cardinality.

I will add some details that have by now been talked about in other comments. Let $F$ be a field and let $X$ be a set of variables. Let $F[X]$ be the ring of polynomials whose variables come from $X$ and coefficients from $F$. Now let $F(X)$ be the field of fractions of $F[X]$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions). You can also view $F(X)$ as the field of rational functions in variables from $X$ with coefficients in $F$. Now $F(X)$ is a new field properly containing $F$. Moreover, $|F(X)|=\max\{|F|,|X|,|\mathbb{N}|\}$.

Comment: how does one "find" an element that is transcendental over $F$ In the case where $F$ was the field of algebraic numbers, we know "before hand" about $K = C$, $k =\pi$. If I give you an an _arbitrary_ field $K'$, how do you know what the corresponding $K$ and $k$ are?

Comment: You can always make an “abstract adjunction”, as in many comments to the other answer.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should clarify that "transcendental" here doesn't mean "transcendental complex number". I mean adjoin a "transcendental variable" like when constructing the field of rational functions over $F$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function

Comment: @SiddharthBhat $F(t)$ is the field of rational functions (fractions where the numerators and denominators are polynomials in the abstract variable $t$ with coefficients from $F$). For instance, a typical element of $\Bbb Q(t)$ (which is thus also an element of $\Bbb C(t)$) is $$\frac{3t^4-8t^3-7t^2+10t+47}{t^5-15t^2+71}$$This field extension goes beyond algebraic extensions, and thus doing it to an algebraically closed field still gives you something new.

Comment: (They are called "rational functions", but they aren't, a priori, functions. You can make them into functions pretty easily, but it is not what they are. They are fractions of polynomials, and that's it. Polynomials aren't functions either, by the way. Again, they can easily be made into functions, but it is not what they are.)